# Select statements during long update

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, update

I've a table

```
MESSAGES 
id (long) | attach_data (image) | ins_date | flag
```

this table contains all messages of my application. During night, my job cleans old attach_data with query

```
update messages set attach_data=0x 
where ins_date< DATEADD(DAY, -120, GETDATE())  
and datalength(image)> 0
```

this is very long query (about 2 hours)

Other processes are always querying same table with

```
select id FROM MESSAGES WHERE Flag = 0 ORDER BY ins_date ASC
```

But during this 2 night hours, this query is not function (timeout expired).
There are a tricks?
I'm running Sql server 2005

Comment: I think using select statement with nolock should resolve your issue.select id FROM MESSAGES WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE Flag = 0 ORDER BY ins_date ASC

Comment: i won't modifiy select statement, because my production application is very sensitive. There aren't hint to update to nolock table?

Comment: UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements ignore the NOLOCK hint.

Comment: If id is the PK, a filtered index on ins_date where flag = 0 should help. This index should not need to be modified by the update.

Comment: You can also always consider batch updates. If you use a TOP(10000) in the update, it'll just do that many records at once. Do this in a WHILE loop until no rows are updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Note: I got to the end of writing this and noticed that sometimes you refer to the data field as `image` and sometimes as `attach_data`.  You'll need to take that into account as you read this.]

You might try breaking up the update statement into multiple batches with TOP:

```
UPDATE TOP (5) messages SET attach_data = 0x 
WHERE ins_date < DATEADD(DAY, -120, GETDATE())  
AND DATALENGTH(image) > 0;
```

Then you'll need to modify your maintenance window to execute this query repeatedly until no records are returned.  You also might want to use a static date parameter specified by the application since the dates will create a moving target as you re-run this query.

Note that this method will cause the maintenance process to take *longer* to process overall, but each batch should complete more quickly and therefore you shouldn't be blocking reads as long.  You can make the whole process faster by increasing the size of the TOP, but each transaction will lock longer.  It's a tradeoff you'll have to play with.

Note also that you can't easily specify an order the records will be updated here since UPDATE doesn't support ORDER BY; you'll just have to keep repeating it until it finishes.

---

If that doesn't work for you, then there are some optimizations you could make.  I would guess that part of the issue is that `DATALENGTH()` is not a very fast function since it has to read the data.  Do you really *need* to test data length here?  Is what you're doing significantly different than this:

```
UPDATE messages SET attach_data = 0x 
WHERE ins_date < DATEADD(DAY, -120, GETDATE())  
AND attach_data <> 0x;
```

---

If you must use `DATALENGTH()` or the above doesn't work, its worth noticing that it *is* deterministic.  That means you can index it.  It may be worthwhile to create an indexed view, or a computed column in the table which has `DATALENGTH()` that you can then index.

Something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW messages_maintenance
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
SELECT id,
    ins_date,
    DATALENGTH(image) AS "image_datalength"
FROM messages;
```

Followed by a unique clustered index on `id`, and then a nonclustered index on `image_datalength`, `ins_date`.  Then you can run:

```
UPDATE messages SET attach_data = 0x
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM messages_maintenance
        WHERE messages_maintenance.id = messages.id
        AND messages_maintenance.image_datalength > 0
        AND messages_maintenance.ins_date < DATEADD(DAY, -120, GETDATE()));
```

Adding a computed column and an index on that would be similar.

Note that this method does add a number of indexes that now have to be maintained by the DB, so it isn't free.

Comment: many thanks for this answer. "Image" is type of attach_data and I can't filter by "attach_data <> 0x

Answer (score 0):

Consider indexing properly and running the cleanup once every minute. That way each batch is automatically tiny. Each day has 1440 such small batches then.

Comment: You should add more details .. like create index on what columns, etc. to improve your answer.

Comment: @Kin that's absolutely basic indexing knowledge. I assume the OP will research that.